# Swift extension of Sequence to check if an intersection exists

Tags: swift, sequence, swift-extensions

My goal is to have a function available through all `Sequence` like Array or Set.

This function should return a `Bool` telling whether there is at least one object present in both sequences or not.

```
// Usage
let s1 = ["hi", "hey", "ho"]
let s2:Set = ["woop", "oi", "yes"]

if s2.intersects(with: s1) {
  print("Happy me, it's a match")
}

extension Sequence where Element:Equatable {
    func intersects<T:Sequence>(with anotherSequence:T) -> Bool
    where T.Element: Equatable {
        //                  ⬇ error: `Extraneous argument label 'where:' in call`
        return self.contains(where: anotherSequence.contains)
    }
}

// doing the same function outside works:
let rez = s1.contains(where: s2.contains)
print(rez)
```

I feel like I'm almost there but I don't understand why the first `contains(where:)` gives me this error.
Both `contains()` and `contains(where:)` belongs to `Sequence` no?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the correct syntax, not sure why the other syntax would not work tho :/

If someone could still explain why the other way does not work, it'd be interesting

```swift
extension Sequence where Element:Equatable {
    func intersects<T:Sequence>(with anotherSequence:T) -> Bool
        where T.Element == Self.Element {
        return self.contains(where: anotherSequence.contains)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would change the method name to `intersects`. Btw you don't need a closure `func intersects<S: Sequence>(with sequence: S) -> Bool
        where S.Element == Element, Element: Equatable { contains(where: sequence.contains) }`

Comment: There's nothing different in your syntax, the difference is in the generic where clause. The problem with your original implementation was that `Equatable` only works for two instances of the same type, so simply stating that both sequences are equatable doesn't guarantee that they can be checked for equality. However, making `Sequence.Element` be `Equatable` AND making `Sequence.Element == OtherSequence.Element` does guarantee that they can be checked for equality.

Comment: By syntax I meant the way to make it works, it was a mistake of language sorry. I indeed thought that by being `Equatable`, it would let me compare between any type. Thank you for the explanation!